# Want to do riposte tests. What is the lowest defense ripostable ncp?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So I am trying to learn more about riposte mechanics. I need a test subject. What is the lowest defense humanoid ncp in dark souls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hollows in Things Betwixt, followed by the Hollow Foot Soldiers in Forest of the Fallen Giants.

Be careful though, enemies only spawn ~7 times per ng...

Comment: in ng+ those foot soldiers get 50% dmg reduction O.O

Comment: As does every other enemy.

Comment: Best way to learn this is PVP XD also there is a Video on youtube explainging all the diffrent wayS of timing when riposting.

Answer (score 0):

Iron keep, ng+, red, invader like alonne captain, has a lot more health but very low defense it seems. I used a malformed skull +10 darkness infused with resonant blade and brightbug to inflict a 3,500 damage backstab on him.